# How do you implement SASTokenProvider for per-container SAS token access?

Tags: azure, databricks

According to the documentation, you can use SAS tokens to access Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, by implementing the `org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.extensions.SASTokenProvider` interface.

See the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sas-access

However, only a [mock implementation](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-azure/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/azurebfs/extensions/MockSASTokenProvider.java) is provided, that uses direct access to the master account key to generate the SAS token:

```
    try {
      AbfsConfiguration abfsConfig = new AbfsConfiguration(configuration, accountName);
      accountKey = Base64.decode(abfsConfig.getStorageAccountKey());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new IOException(ex);
    }
    generator = new ServiceSASGenerator(accountKey);
```

It is completely meaningless to restrict access by providing a SAS token when the code is running in a context that has access to the master account key, and obviously this is a mock implementation used for testing purposes only.

So, a correct implementation of this class would:

- be run in a [package-cell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/_static/notebooks/package-cells.html) so it has access to the secret scopes
- be implemented in scala, because java is not supported
- fetch the SAS token from the secret scope
- return the SAS token

How can such an implementation be written?

Here is the most basic and trivial version of the solution that proves that this *is possible to do*:

```
%scala
package com.foo

class CustomTokenProvider extends org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.extensions.SASTokenProvider {
  def getSASToken(accountName: String,fileSystem: String,path: String,operation: String): String = {
    return "sp=...etc etc"
  }
  def initialize(configuration: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration, accountName: String): Unit = {    
  }
}

...

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.STORAGE_ACC.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.STORAGE_ACC.dfs.core.windows.net", "com.foo.CustomTokenProvider")
```

```
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://sandbox@STORAGE_ACC.dfs.core.windows.net/")
> [FileInfo(path='abfss://sandbox@STORAGE_ACC.dfs.core.windows.net/t.py', name='t.py', size=112)]
```

```
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://restricted@STORAGE_ACC.dfs.core.windows.net/")
> Operation failed: &#34;Server failed to authenticate the request.
```

However, how can this implementation to changed to pull the key from the secret store instead of being hard-coded?

Note **specifically** that:

- this refers to the abfss driver, *not* the legacy wasb driver.
- the question is specifically with regard to getting the SAS token from the secret store which can be restricted at a group / user level; assigning the token at a cluster level (eg. env variable) is not a valid solution because it means all cluster users are granted the same permissions.
- ...and yes, I know, databricks has it's own custom identity provider system (Unity), but that only applies to datasets in the hive metastore. This question is specifically regarding the lower level storage account access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%scala
package com.foo

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.DefinedByConstructorParams

import scala.util.Try

import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

trait DBUtilsApi {
    type SecretUtils
    type SecretMetadata
    type SecretScope
    val secrets: SecretUtils
}

object ReflectiveDBUtils extends DBUtilsApi {
    
    private lazy val dbutils: DBUtils =
        Class.forName("com.databricks.service.DBUtils$").getField("MODULE$").get().asInstanceOf[DBUtils]

    override lazy val secrets: SecretUtils = dbutils.secrets

    type DBUtils = AnyRef {
        val secrets: SecretUtils
    }

    type SecretUtils = AnyRef {
        def get(scope: String, key: String): String
        def getBytes(scope: String, key: String): Array[Byte]
        def list(scope: String): Seq[SecretMetadata]
        def listScopes(): Seq[SecretScope]
    }

    type SecretMetadata = DefinedByConstructorParams { val key: String }

    type SecretScope = DefinedByConstructorParams { val name: String }
}

class VaultTokenProvider extends org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.extensions.SASTokenProvider {
  def getSASToken(accountName: String,fileSystem: String,path: String,operation: String): String = {
    return ReflectiveDBUtils.secrets.get("scope", "SECRET")
  }
  def initialize(configuration: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration, accountName: String): Unit = {    
  }
}
```

...

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.bidbtests.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.bidbtests.dfs.core.windows.net", "com.foo.VaultTokenProvider")
```

This is basic example only; the real solution will select the correct secret based on account and file system.

Answer (score -2):

## You can access Azure ADLS(Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2) to Azure Databricks by using following code, you just need to add Storage account name and SAS token key, SAS token will get from storage account

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS")

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider")

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<SAS_Token>")

### List to show files avaliable in container

dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/InputData/")